# Rotating on drag with 2 fingers

Tags: flutter, dart

right now I am looking for a proper widget to rotate object with 2 fingers.

Do you have any tips for it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [MultiDragGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/MultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html) is what you're looking for.

```
class DraggableWidget extends StatefulWidget implements MultiDragGestureRecognizer {
...
}
```